# How show hint in Hebrew in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How show hint message in Hebrew language?.If I remove "`android:inputType="phone"`" 
message show.

I have tried "`android:ellipsize="start"`", add some unicode but not work.

Is any way to show hint in Hebrew with "`android:inputType="phone"`"?

**Code:**

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/mobile"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="36dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@drawable/drawrect_layout"
   android:hint="@string/mobile"
   android:inputType="phone"
   android:padding="6dp"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: Are you using this in LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting width to `0dp` that is why you are getting this problem. Please use `wrap_content or fill_parent`. I have edited this and is working at my side.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="mobile"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text" />
```